# Logic equivalent for string comparison

Tags: ruby, if-statement, logic

Why are these expressions different:

```
!x == "string"
```

and

```
x != "string"
```

At least first expression does not enter my `if`, and when I change it, `if` code is executed.

Comment: What do you think `!x == "string"` does? Hint: operator precedence

Comment: I assume you wanted `if !(x == "string")`. Consider using `unless x == "string"` instead.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> ***At least first expression does not enter my if***

Here is my explanation :

`!` has higher precedence then `==`. So in your expression `!x == "string"` will be internally represented as `(!x) == "string"`

`!x` either will be evaluted to `true` or `false`, which are `TrueClass` or `FalseClass` object respectively. Now Let's check whose `#==` method is used by `true` and `false` object.

```
true.method(:==).owner
# => BasicObject
false.method(:==).owner
# => BasicObject
```

> [`Basic#==`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-3D-3D-) : Equality — At the Object level, == returns true only if obj and other are the same object.

As per the above definition your code `!x == "string"` should always be evaluated to `false`.

Comment: @JanDvorak Opps!! sorry.. to bother you then.. :)) please don't mind..tell me if any more improvement is needed to this answer.

Comment: Is a long answer, I will mark this, don't want my error to punish you.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say x is "foo"

```
!x == "string"
```

is expanded to

```
false == "string"
```

which is totally different from your second example, which is expanded to:

```
"foo" != "string"
```

Comment: It’s probably worth noting that this is because `!x == "string"` is equivalent to `(!x) == "string"` rather than `!(x == "string")`.

Answer (score 2):

What do  you expect "not x" to be?  Will it be equal to "string" or any string for that matter?

It is simply a totally different statement.

You mention an if statement, so this must the condition that you are using for a logic statement.  Since not x will never be equal to a string, then the if statements condition will always be false.